# Can I allow access to a site available only on LAN to another user connected to my computer?

Tags: networking

So I know I can use ngrok to project a website I host on localhost to be available publicly. Can I do the same for another site, which is only available in the local network, but not hosted on my machine?

For example, there is a website hosted on http://testing.stackoverflow.com, which is a version of the website that's only available to people connected to the internal wifi, but I want to so my customer a new feature that's only available on that website, without making it available to everyone. The customer can only access it while somehow connected to my machine. Can ngrok or a similar tool do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **ngrok** to expose any host, accessible to you, to the internet. See https://ngrok.com/docs#non-local.

You have already used ngrok to tunnel traffic between internet and your localhost. Similarly, if you want to expose a web server in your LAN, say `192.168.22.22`, just execute `ngrok http 192.168.22.22:80`, instead of `ngrok http 80`.

Comment: Sweet. I saw that, but didn't have an internal website to test with, so I wasn't sure. Thanks!